# (Си) Что будет, если освободить память массива, проинициализированного NULL?

Tags: c, массивы, память, free

Будет ли ошибкой освобождать память пустого массива, который проинициализирован NULL, при помощи `free`? Eсли нет, то что произойдёт и почему это не будет ошибкой?
(В си)

```
int *arr = NULL;
free (arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Согласно стандарту в функцию `free` разрешено передавать null, и при этом функция должна ничего не сделать.

https://ru.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free